# Is there still gas refund for SSTORE to 0 instructions?

Tags: gas, gas-estimate, optimization, gas-refund

I'm trying to optimize a contract and wondering if I can still rely on gas refunds to optimize for gas?

https://twitter.com/n2ckchong/status/1365843261567365121

I've read from this tweet that there was a proposal last year to remove gas refund for self destruct, was it passed? is that why chi gas token and GST lost most of their value?
Would there still be gas refund for SSTORE to 0 instructions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has been implemented in the [London Upgrade](https://ethereum.org/en/history/#london) through [EIP-3529](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3529)

> Remove gas refunds for SELFDESTRUCT, and reduce gas refunds for SSTORE to a lower level